# How to change the type of all elements to a single type(from int to str)?

Tags: python

I have a list `a=['1','2',3,4,5,6]`
How do i get the list `a=['1','2','3','4','5','6']`?

I have tried using `str`. but doesn't work
[image: my try out]

Comment: I have posted my tryout in the question

Comment: You must have assigned some value to `str` before that. Don't use `builtin` names as `user variables` in your programs

Answer (score 6):

You can use a list comprehension:

```
a=[str(elt) for elt in a]
```

Comment: It doesn't help the question, because the code in the question is using list comprehension。

Comment: Actually he edited his question after I suggested him to use list comprehensions.

Answer (score 1):

List comprehension:

```
a = [str(x) for x in a]
```

Map:

```
a = list(map(str, a))
```

Answer (score 1):

2nd Approach:

```
import numpy as np
a= np.array(a,dtype=str)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to take each element and convert it into string. Converting the whole list at once(like `a=str(a)` ), won't work.

```
for idx, element in enumerate(a):
    a[idx] = str(element)
```

Answer (score 1):

your code is ok, but str is a build-in function， you may have renamed str to some value, this will got a err.

```
>>> str = 'str'
>>> str('1')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

Answer (score 1):

```
a=['1','2',3,4,5,6]
a=[str(a[i]) for i in range(len(a))]
```

output

```
['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6']
```